# Need function to return find top node in hierarchy given flat data

Tags: excel, vba, recursion, indexing, match

I've seen some questions about Excel VBA recursive lookup functions, but none seem to work for my purposes. I need help!

I have a table called "Epics." Each Epic is assigned a type that indicates its level on a hierarchy. At the bottom of the hierarchy are features. Then project. Then programs. Then charters. In other words, a charter is a collection of programs. A program is a collection of projects. A project is a collection of features. If the data is good, I want to be able to start with a feature and recursively lookup its parent until I find an Epic of type charter.

To make this possible, we need a relationship between rows. In my case this is a text field called "Parent."

Here is some sample data and psuedo code. Note that I am hiding all the columns with irrelevant data (D, E, F, G, I, J, K, L) to make the table easier to follow.

```
   | A       | B       | C           | H          | M
1  | ID      | TYPE    | TITLE       | PARENT_NAME| CHARTERID
2  | E-01958 | Feature | Apples      | Lemons     | E-01847
3  | E-01837 | Feature | Bananas     |            | Error - Orphaned Feature
4  | E-01847 | Charter | Grapes      |            | E-01847 
5  | E-01865 | Project | Lemons      | Limes      | E-01847
6  | E-01415 | Program | Limes       | Pineapples | E-01847
7  | E-01168 |         | Pears       | Melons     | E-01951  
8  | E-01954 | Feature | Kiwis       | Lemons     | E-01847
9  | E-01951 | Charter | Melons      |            | E-01951
10 | E-01901 | Program | Pineapples  | Grapes     | E-01847
11 | E-09123 | Project | Raspberries |            | Error – Orphaned Project
12 | E-98123 |         | Strawberries|            | Error Orphaned NA
13 | E-01872 | Program | Tomatoes    |            | Error- Orphaned Program
```

Explanation of Function Value (Col M):

```
Row 1: Headers

Row 2 (Apples)
Type for Apples is Feature, not Charter, so find parent.
Parent for Apples is Lemons.
Type for Lemons is Project, not Charter, so find parent.
Parent for Lemons is Limes.
Type for Limes is Program, not Charter, so find parent.
Parent for Limes is Pineapples.
Type for Pineapples is Program, not Charter, so find parent.
Parent for Pineapples is Grapes.
Type for Grapes is Charter. Success!
Function returns E-01847 (ID for Grapes) to M2.

Row 3 (Bananas)
Type for Bananas is Feature, not Charter, so find parent.
Parent for Bananas is null, so we cannot continue the search.
Function returns "Error - Orphaned Feature" to M3.
Note: The error here is really "Error - Orphaned " & IFNA([Type],"NA")

Row 4 (Grapes)
Type for Grapes is Charter. Success!
Function returns E-01847 (ID for Grapes) to M4.

Row 5 (Lemons)
Same logic path as R2
Function returns E-01847 (ID for Grapes) to M5.

Row 6 (Limes)
Same logic path as R2
Function returns E-01847 (ID for Grapes) to M6.

Row 7 (Pears)
Type for Pears is Program, not Charter, so find parent.
Parent for Pears is Melons
Type for Melons is Charter. Success!
Function returns E-01951 (ID for Melons) to M7.

Row 8 (Kiwis)
Same logic path as R2
Function returns E-01847 (ID for Grapes) to M8.

Row 9 (Melons)
Type for Melons is Charter. Success!
Function returns E-01951 (ID for Grapes) to M9.

Row 10 (Pineapples)
Same logic path as R2
Function returns E-01847 (ID for Grapes) to M10.

Row 11 (Raspberries)
Type for Raspberries is Project, not Charter, so find parent.
Parent for Raspberries is null, so we cannot continue the search.
Function returns "Error - Orphaned Project" to M11.

Row 12 (Strawberries)
Type for Strawberries is null not Charter, so find parent.
Parent for Strawberries is null, so we cannot continue the search.
Function returns "Error - Orphaned NA" to M12.

Row 13 (Tomatoes)
Type for Tomatoes is Program, not Charter, so find parent.
Parent for Tomatoes is null, so we cannot continue the search.
Function returns "Error - Orphaned program" to M13.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry the table is poorly formatted. I can't figure out how to place a table in the message. All the formatting gets stripped out. I'll try again with pipes...

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just "unflatten" the data into normalize into 4 tables - one for each of Charters, Programs, Projects, Features?

Comment: Let's imagine that I did that. I would still need a function that checks four tables N times. For example, a feature in tbl_Epic_Features might have a parent in tbl_Epic_Projects, but that project may itself have its parent in the tbl_Epic_Projects table. In other words, I am still left with a recursive lookup.

Comment: Actually you'd be left with a series of fairly simple SQL join statements. You describe the structure as hierarchical, so it would just be a series of 1-M relationships.

Comment: The data is exported from a separate system in one flat file. I would first need to split the data, which I guess could be a macro. Then I could consider this approach, but I still need help to write it. I am way out of my depth. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ProcessEpics()
    Const ID = "ID"
    Const EPICTYPE = "EPICTYPE"
    Const PARENT = "PARENT"
    Const CHARTERID = "CHARTERID"
    Const HIEARCHY = "HIEARCHY"

    Dim arData, arResults, key
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim List As Object, subList As Object, refList As Object

    Set List = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("Epics")
        lastRow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        arData = .Rows("2:" & lastRow).Columns("A:H").Value2
    End With

    For x = 1 To UBound(arData)
        If Not List.Exists(arData(x, 3)) And arData(x, 3) <> "" Then
            Set subList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            subList.Add ID, arData(x, 1)
            subList.Add EPICTYPE, arData(x, 2)
            subList.Add PARENT, arData(x, 8)
            subList.Add CHARTERID, vbNullString
            subList.Add HIEARCHY, vbNullString

            List.Add arData(x, 3), subList
        End If
    Next

    For Each key In List
        Set refList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        Set subList = List(key)
        refList.Add subList(PARENT)

        Do
            If subList(PARENT) <> vbNullString Then Set subList = List(subList(PARENT))
            If refList.Contains(subList(PARENT)) Then
                refList.Add subList(PARENT)
                Exit Do
            End If
            refList.Add subList(PARENT)
        Loop Until subList(PARENT) = vbNullString

        If subList(EPICTYPE) = "Charter" Then
            List(key)(CHARTERID) = subList(ID)
        Else
            List(key)(CHARTERID) = "Error " & subList(EPICTYPE)
        End If

        List(key)(HIEARCHY) = Join(refList.ToArray, "->")

    Next

    With Worksheets("Epics")
        For x = 2 To lastRow
            .Cells(x, "M") = List(.Cells(x, 3).Text)(CHARTERID)
            .Cells(x, "N") = List(.Cells(x, 3).Text)(HIEARCHY)
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Error: Out of memory

Comment: I'm getting a file not found from the download link.

Comment: Error: Out of memory on line: "Set refList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")"

Comment: Note: In my sample I call one column PARENT NAME. In the real data it is called PORTFOLIO ITEM

Comment: You already sent me the workbook.  It ran fine for me,  Are you trying to use this as a worksheet function?

Comment: What I really was hoping for was a function that calculates the charter for each epic (portfolio item). I'm not sure what this subroutine does yet, because I have not been able to run it. Tell me where to place the routine and I'll try it from there. Thanks!

Comment: Place it in a standard code module and run it to update all the charter IDs.    If you are making changes to the table; I suggest adding a button to the worksheet to update the charter IDs.